# JavaScript reduce on array of objects failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reduce

Novice JS developer, need some help in identifying what I am doing wrong.

I have an array of objects

```
const ll = [{name:"a", ids:[1]}, {name:"b", ids:[2,3]}];
```

I want to convert it to following

```
[
  { name: 'a', ids: null, id: 1 },
  { name: 'b', ids: null, id: 2 },
  { name: 'b', ids: null, id: 3 }
]
```

essentially adding one record for each element in `ids` array.

This is the code I wrote

```
ll.reduce((r,o) => 
  r.concat(o.ids.map(i => {
       const r1 = o;
       r1.id = i;
       r1.ids = null;
       return r1;})),[])
```

What I am getting is

```
[
  { name: 'a', ids: null, id: 1 },
  { name: 'b', ids: null, id: 3 },
  { name: 'b', ids: null, id: 3 }
]
```

why 2 is missing & 3 is repeated?

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `Array#flatMap()`:

(A terser version can be found in the snippet below.)

```js
const result = ll.flatMap(object => {
  // For each original object
  return object.ids.map(id => {
    // ...create a new object for each id in it.
    const newObject = structuredClone(object);

    // Set .ids to null and assign id to .id.
    newObject.ids = null;
    newObject.id = id;

    return newObject;
  })
});
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const ll = [
  { name: "a", ids: [1] },
  { name: "b", ids: [2, 3] }
];

const result = ll.flatMap(
  object => object.ids.map(
    id => Object.assign(structuredClone(object), { ids: null, id })
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```